# Snowflake Swap Feature

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Say I am swapping a prod table table_a with another table table_b which is in dev by using the below query-

alter table prod.table_a swap with dev.table_b;

Does it retain all the metadata like retention_time, roles, grants etc in the original table i.e, table_a? Also will there be any issues if I am doing time travel on the prod table like after doing the swap?

Still can't get my head over it as I am doing some data fixes in dev table and after that I want to swap with the prod table.

Please let me know your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

This statement:

```
alter TABLE_A swap with TABLE_B
```

is the equivalent of doing this in a single transaction:

```
alter TABLE_A      rename to TABLE_A_TEMP;
alter TABLE_B      rename to TABLE_A;
alter TABLE_A_TEMP rename to TABLE_B;
```

So this is literally a renaming operation. It swaps nothing but the names of the tables. Everything else remains the same.

The reason the swap command exists is because of this note in the documentation:

> Explicit transactions should contain only DML statements and query statements. DDL statements implicitly commit active transactions (for details, see the DDL section).

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/transactions.html

So the `swap` command provides a way to rename TABLE_A to TABLE_B and vice versa in a single transaction. It cannot be done using `begin` and `commit` in a single transaction. The swap command enables this when it needs to be done in a single transaction. This is so it does not miss DML operations in pipelines or break select queries on a highly-active table in the brief instant the swap would take in the three-line renaming process.

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE SWAP command will swap the contents and metadata between two specified tables, including any integrity constraints defined for the tables and access control privilege grants. Retention_time will also be swapped. It can be considered as two tables being renamed in a single transaction.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table.html#parameters

Time travel will be based on the retention time defined in the table and against the table mapping internally.

```
describe table testdb1.testsch1.testtab1; --- with 1 column and retention 1

describe table testdb2.testsch2.testtab2; --- with 2 columns and retention 2

insert into testdb1.testsch1.testtab1 values (1),(2);

delete from testdb1.testsch1.testtab1 where col1=1; --- Query ID is 01a609ef-0604-911c-0000-01d10b9cd2ae

alter table testdb1.testsch1.testtab1 swap with testdb2.testsch2.testtab2;

describe table testdb1.testsch1.testtab1; --- with 2 columns and retention 2

describe table testdb2.testsch2.testtab2; --- with 1 column and retention 1

select * from testdb2.testsch2.testtab2 before(statement => '01a609ef-0604-911c-0000-01d10b9cd2ae'); -- show the data
  
select * from testdb1.testsch1.testtab1 before(statement => '01a609ef-0604-911c-0000-01d10b9cd2ae'); -- will not show the data
```

Comment: I have a cloned a prod table in dev and then would be doing a swap after doing all the data fixes in the cloned table. So what points should I keep in mind before swapping?